# Kubernetes ingress mutual authentication on subpath

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have a microservice application and I want to implement a mutual authentication only with specific subpath not for all host.

I tried to create 2 different ingress, but it's seems that at the end they are merged together because they share the annotation

Here an example of my 2 ingesses

Non mutual paths ingress

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-dev
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-dev
spec:
  rules:
    - host: >-
        myhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /path-1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-1
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /path-2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-2
                port:
                  number: 3000
  tls:
  - secretName: secret
```

mutual path ingress

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-2
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "dev/mutual-cert"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-dev
spec:
  rules:
    - host: >-
        myhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /path-3
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-3
                port:
                  number: 3000
  tls:
  - secretName: secret
```

The problems is that if I add both ingress, mutual auth also applies to subpaths for the first entry (probably because at the end the ingresses are merged together).

There's a way to split the annotation based on subpath with the same host? Or to set mutual with different subpath?